# SQL to gather data from one table while counting records in another

Tags: sql, count

I have a users table and a songs table, I want to select all the users in the users table while counting how many songs they have in the songs table. I have this SQL but it doesn't work, can someone spot what i'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT jos_mfs_users.*, COUNT(jos_mfs_songs.id) as song_count 
FROM jos_mfs_users 
INNER JOIN jos_mfs_songs
ON jos_mfs_songs.artist=jos_mfs_users.id
```

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does it give an error, or just unexpected results?

Comment: I'm guessing the song count is 1 for every record.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The inner join won't work, because it joins every matching row in the songs table with the users table.

```
SELECT jos_mfs_users.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(jos_mfs_songs.id) 
        FROM jos_mfs_songs
        WHERE jos_mfs_songs.artist=jos_mfs_users.id) as song_count 
FROM jos_mfs_users 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(jos_mfs_songs.id) 
        FROM jos_mfs_songs
        WHERE jos_mfs_songs.artist=jos_mfs_users.id) > 10
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that works. What about if I want to use the song_count in a WHERE clause, because when I put WHERE song_count > 10, it doesn't work. How do I refer to the song_count value. Help much appreciated!

Comment: Use `HAVING` to compare to an aggregate like a `COUNT`

Comment: You could add the (SELECT COUNT()...) clause to a WHERE statement. I'll edit it to show that.  You could try the "having" clause as well.

Comment: `SELECT A.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.a_id = A.id) AS TOT FROM A` is a much more simple soluiton

Answer (score 3):

There's a `GROUP BY` clause missing, e.g.

```
SELECT jos_mfs_users.id, COUNT(jos_mfs_songs.id) as song_count 
FROM jos_mfs_users 
INNER JOIN jos_mfs_songs
ON jos_mfs_songs.artist=jos_mfs_users.id
GROUP BY jos_mfs_users.id
```

If you want to add more columns from `jos_mfs_users` in the select list you should add them in the `GROUP BY`clause as well.

Answer (score 3):

Changes:

- Don't do `SELECT *`...specify your fields.  I included ID and NAME, you can add more as needed but put them in the `GROUP BY` as well
- Changed to a `LEFT JOIN` - `INNER JOIN` won't list any users that have no songs
- Added the `GROUP BY` so it gives a valid count and is valid syntax

  ```
  SELECT u.id, u.name COUNT(s.id) as song_count 
  FROM jos_mfs_users AS u
  LEFT JOIN jos_mfs_songs AS S
      ON s.artist = u.id
  GROUP BY U.id, u.name
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jos_mfs_songs as songs WHERE songs.artist=users.id) as song_count 
FROM 
  jos_mfs_users as users
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a `GROUP BY` clause to use aggregate functions (like `COUNT()`, for example)

So, assuming that `jos_mfs_users.id` is a primary key, something like this will work:

```
SELECT jos_mfs_users.*, COUNT( jos_mfs_users.id ) as song_count 
FROM jos_mfs_users 
INNER JOIN jos_mfs_songs
  ON jos_mfs_songs.artist = jos_mfs_users.id
GROUP BY jos_mfs_users.id
```

Notice that

- since you are grouping by user id, you will get one result per distinct user id in the results
- the thing you need to `COUNT()` is the number of rows that are being grouped (in this case the number of results per user)

Comment: -1 For `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY` on a single field - he will get random records per `users.id`, if his SQL engine even allows it (most won't)

Comment: How will this return random records? For each result row grouped by jos_mfs_users.id, all fields from jos_mfs_users will be the same! And no fields from jos_mfs_songs are `SELECT`ed (there's only a `COUNT()`). I think you're mistaken!

Comment: You are **ASSUMING** all other fields will be the same.  OP did not indicate it was a unique field or PK.  **Selecting fields not in your `GROUP BY` or in an aggregation is an anti-pattern to be avoided.**  Period.

Comment: Ok, you are correct. I've edited the answer to state my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a many to many relationship. By that I mean it looks like there can be several records in the users table for each user, one of each song they have.
I would have three tables.
Users, which has one record for each user
Songs, which has one record for each song
USER_SONGS, which has one record for each user/song combination
Now, you can do a count of the songs each user has by doing a query on the intermediate table. You can also find out how many users have a particular song.

This will tell you how many songs each user has

```
select id, count(*) from USER_SONGS
GROUP BY id;
```

This will tell you how many users each song has

```
select artist, count(*) from USER_SONGS
GROUP BY artist;
```

I'm sure you will need to tweak this for your needs, but it may give you the type of results you are looking for.

You can also join either of these queries to the other two tables to find the user name, and/or artist name.

HTH
Harv Sather

ps I am not sure if you are looking for song counts or artist counts.